# What does the notation $1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ mean?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

I came across this problem with the Rayleigh distribution where this notation was used:

$f(x|\theta) = \displaystyle\frac{x}{\theta^2}\exp(-\displaystyle\frac{x^2}{2\theta^2})1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$

What does the notation $1_{[0,\infty)}(x)$ mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is likely the [indicator function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function), which in this case is defined by

$$
1_{[0,\infty)}(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & \text{if}\ x\in[0,\infty), \\
0 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: +1 for first correct answer. Why not just $x \ge 0$ for the first condition?

Comment: @EthanBolker Thank you! I wanted to mimic the way the indicator function of an arbitrary set works.

Answer (score 2):

$1_A$ is an indicator function.  $1_A(x) = 1$ if $x\in A$ and $1_A(x) = 0$ otherwise.